# Testing react app with cypress and firestore shows Timed out retrying: cy.wait()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, e2e-testing, cypress

I'm using `react 16.8.1`, `cypress 3.1.5` and `firebase 5.5.3` for e2e tests.

Currently I need to wait for the page to load all the components and then run the tests like getting a button and clicking on it.

Before each test, the programm checks if the user is logged in and if so, it'll wait for firebase to send some `POST` and `GET` requests.

Unfortunately cypress shows `CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.wait() timed out waiting 100000ms for the 1st response to the route: 'googleGETRoute'. No response ever occurred.` for both GET and POST requests, which makes clicking or continuing the tests impossible.

Before each request I run the following:

```
beforeEach(function () {
    cy.server().route({ url: /https:\/\/.*google.*/, method: "POST" }).as("googleRoute");
    cy.server().route({ url: /https:\/\/.*google.*/, method: "GET" }).as("googleGETRoute");
    cy.visit('/event');
    cy.wait('@googleRoute', xhr => {
        cy.url().then((url) => {
            if (url === 'http://localhost:3000/login') {
                cy.loginByForm(testUserAccount, testUserPassword);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And to delete an event:

```
it('should deleteEvent', function() {
    cy.wait('@googleGETRoute', { responseTimeout:100000, log:true });
    cy.wait('@googleRoute', { responseTimeout: 100000, log:true });

    deleteEvent(event);
    cy.contains(event.title).should('not.be.visible');
});
```

still no responses from firestore. I've also checked [#1652](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1652) and [#2374](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2374) which are almost the same as this problem.

Has anyone faced this issue before? Would appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't rely on firestore or firebase to start a test because it's an external service that you have no control over especially

- when are these firestore requests sent?
- what are these requests for?
- how do they work?

If we don't understand, we cannot expect Cypress knows what's going on because it's a framework.

Instead, you can just wait for a specific component to be available. By default, the cy.get command has [a built-in timeout](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get.html#Arguments). It'll wait for the given component to be rendered before failing a test.

In  your case, you can increase the timeout of the very first `cy.get` which, I think, in `deleteEvent()`. In addition, you need get rid of all `cy.server & cy.wait` for firestore which are unreliable and useless.

Comment: great answer, it helped me fix a lot of flakiness in my tests.